# Are these instructions valid for MIPS?

Tags: mips

Are these instructions valid for MIPS?

```
 lw $t6, list($t0)     # Load list[i]
 lw $t7, list($t1)     # Load list[j]
copy_second_remaining:
    bge $t1, $a3, merge_done
    lw $t7, list($t1)
    sw $t7, 0($t5)
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    addi $t2, $t2, 4
    j copy_second_remaining
```

Kept getting index out of bound when using these to store or load from the memory

Comment: Why is this tagged [deep-learning]?

Comment: Yes, they're valid, though some are pseudo instructions.  If you want help with an error message, then quote the entire error message.